# Boolean functions in Go

Tags: go

Please help, I'm new with Go. I wrote function passing a string a regex and return boolan. my test keeps failing when validating correct format of  Date of birth.

My test:

```
func TestIsMatchingRegex(t *testing.T) {
t.Parallel()
var tests = []struct {
        dob      string
        reg      string
        expected bool
        desc     string
    }{
        {dob: "1928-06-05", reg: `[12][0-9]{3}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]`, expected: true, desc: "test1"},
        {dob: "1928/06/05", reg: `[12][0-9]{3}-[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]`, expected: false, desc: "test2"},
    }
    for _, test := range tests {
        actual := IsMatchingRegex(test.dob, test.reg)
        assert.Equal(t, actual, test.expected, test.desc)
    }

}
```

Matching function boolean

```
func IsMatchingRegex(s string, regex string) bool {
validFormat := regexp.MustCompile(regex)
matched := validFormat.MatchString(s)
if validFormat {
    return false
}

return true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test isn't failing, it can't compile because `validFormat` is a `Regexp` not a `bool`.

Your bool is `matched`, but you could simply return the result of `MatchString` (or not use a separate function at all since it's a single line)

```
func IsMatchingRegex(s string, regex string) bool {
    return regexp.MustCompile(regex).MatchString(s)
}
```

Comment: That said, probably not a good idea to use `MustCompile` here.  It panics if the regex doesn't compile.  Should probably either return an error, or simply false, if that's the case.  "Must" type methods are best used for globals (which are run when the program starts, and panics at program launch are fine.  It's the ones during operation that suck) or for tests.

Comment: Also agree with JimB here.  There's not much difference between calling `IsMatchingRegex(s, r)` and `regexp.MustCompile(r).MatchString(s)`.  No need to be a function.  That change would also let you define the date regex as a global, instead of it being an input string, which avoids accidental mistypes or copy-paste errors.

Comment: I see your point, thank you. Reason we are using a function here for usability. we have multiple regex validations in model.